# how to rebuild provider Selector but not rebuild child of them

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I know Consumer can do it by passing  child widget as parameter to a child of the builder, but I don't know in Selector 
this is some docs https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider#my-widget-rebuilds-too-often-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. The selectors also have a child. and I can use it similar to Consumer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid unnecessary rebuild is to use the [Selector class](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector/Selector.html) from the provider package. There might be a scenario where you only need to call a method from your ViewModel but not necessarily need to listen to the changes. You can do this with the optional **shouldRebuild** argument in the constructor to return false. So the the widget under the selector is never rebuilt.

A code example:

```
Selector<HomeModel, HomeModel>(
      shouldRebuild: (prev, next) => false,
      selector: (_, model) => model,
      builder: (_, data, child) {
        return CurvedNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            data.currentIndex = index;
          },
        );
      },
    );
```